# Axes set-up with matlab imshow

Tags: image, matlab, imshow

I have two images (I1 and I2) that I want to plot through subplot as follows. For sake of simplicity I created two fake images with size 512x512 pixels.

```
I1 = randn(512);
I2 = randn(512);
% display 
f1 = figure();
axis on;
subplot(1,2,1), imshow(uint8(I1));
subplot(1,2,2), imshow(uint8(I2));
```

I want the Y axis to show just the following ticks: 0 100 200 300 400 500. Therefore exactly as the X axis, so that it is clear that the image size is also bigger than 500 pixels. How can I do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you only have grayscale images and need to display ticks, I would really recommend using [`image`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) or [`imagesc`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html). `imshow` is meant to not show ticks, because it displays the image as a picture.

Comment: @VaheTshitoyan the problem is that with image or imagesc I can not preserve the true image colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the axis on to the end of the script and specify the XTick and XTickLabel properties.

```
I1 = randn(512);
I2 = randn(512);
% display 
f1 = figure();

s1=subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(uint8(I1));
set(s1,'XTick',0:100:500);
set(s1,'XTickLabel',0:100:500);
axis on;

s2=subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(uint8(I2));
set(s2,'XTick',0:100:500);
set(s2,'XTickLabel',0:100:500);
axis on;
```

Comment: I tried your script and for the Y-axis it shows instead 0 50 100 150 and so on...

Comment: It looks like that this has to do with the window size. Making the window smaller will show the right axes.

Comment: simply substituted XTick and XTickLabel with the correspondent Y parameters and works great. I didn't realize that before! Thanks a lot!